# Left radioactivity in Hiroshima and Nagasaki

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

What is the level of the left radioactivity in Hiroshima and Nagasaki?

It seems that people there live very well. So, the radioactivity is very low?

Comment: There's a few factors to safe radioactive levels.   A bomb is mostly designed to be destructive, not designed to leave a lingering danger, though Atomic bombs do a bit of both.  The radiation released in a Nuclear accident is often much higher than an atomic bomb, but the explosive power is far lower.   The most dangerous period after a nuclear bomb goes off (ignoring the initial blast) is the first few weeks/couple months, people are advised to not open their windows, keep themselves covered/wear a mask if they go outside and not drink the water, but the risk doesn't last all that long.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about physics

Comment: Saying this very carefully because I don't mean to trivialize the human suffering at Hiroshima and Nagasaki: in the grand scheme of things, bombs involve pretty trivial amounts of fuel. Fukushima I before its demise took about *four hours* to output the same energy as the Nagasaki bomb. So the amount of waste from the bomb fuel is pretty small. Most of the radiation is short lived isotopes from the irradiation of dirt and other matter. It's lethal, but highly unstable (the two tend to go together) and short lived.

Comment: Safecast has detailed maps over [Hiroshima](https://safecast.org/tilemap/?y=34.3829&x=132.4391&z=13&l=0&m=0) and [Nagasaki](https://safecast.org/tilemap/?y=32.808&x=130.031&z=12&l=0&m=0). Safecast is a crowd-sourced site that lets people post their radioactivity measurements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the radiation both in Hiroshima and Nagasaki is very low, well, operationally non-existent. [The radiation levels match](http://zidbits.com/2013/11/is-nagasaki-and-hiroshima-still-radioactive/) the world average background radiation of 0.87 millisieverts per year.

The bombs were optimized to have the maximum destructive power. That included a rather high altitude. The Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombs exploded in 580 and 500 meters above the ground, respectively. At this high altitude, virtually no radioactive material has gotten to the ground.

The atoms around the bomb vaporized and escaped the location of the explosion by a speed that isn't negligible relatively to the speed of light. So these atoms have spread all over the atmosphere – and some of them have escaped the Earth's gravitational field, too.

A few kilograms of radioactive isotopes may have been absorbed by the ground but these kilograms were distributed over several squared kilometers of the surface. The density of the radioactive material resulting from this amazing dilution is very small. Isotopes with a short lifetime fade away quickly; and those with a long halftime such as plutonium are causing too small an amount of radioactivity, a flip side of the longevity.

The Trinity site where a similar bomb was tested may still see an elevation of radioactivity today. It's because of a much smaller area over which the radioactive material was distributed (due to the much smaller altitude).

Life was burned from Hiroshima and Nagasaki but on the following spring, vegetation returned there and the ecosystems were ready to operate normally. From this long-term viewpoint, nuclear bombs are safe and healthy tools.

Comment: 'safe and healthy tools'. In what long term point of view can you view 200,000+ people dying being *healthy* or *safe*? If you mean to say, they don't pose permanent damage to the area for the ecosystem, then sure I'll agree. It is very annoying, to say the least, when you belittle such a tragic event in human history.

Comment: They weren't primarily tragic events. They were intentional acts supported by lots of human creativity and balanced political reasoning designed to make the world as good as possible among the conceivable alternatives. This decision has saved millions of lives by pushing Japan towards surrender.

Comment: I'm afraid I must disagree. Regardless of it being better than the 'conceivable' outcomes, nuclear weapons are simply a destructive tool used by humans in order to invoke fear and negativity on others. It was used on civilians, after all. Just because it was an optimal solution doesn't make it a *healthy* or *safe* tool (At least by my definition). I guess Stalin's words hold weight. *"A single death is a tragedy; a million deaths is a statistic."*

Answer (score -1):

From the Wikipedia article on the [Trinity site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_(nuclear_test)) where the first atomic bomb was tested. This is the same type of bomb as used over Nagasaki.

> More than seventy years after the test, residual radiation at the site
>   is about ten times higher than normal background radiation in the
>   area. The amount of radioactive exposure received during a one-hour
>   visit to the site is about half of the total radiation exposure which
>   a U.S. adult receives on an average day from natural and medical
>   sources

I visited the site as a small boy in 1963. I suspect things were a little looser then. The site had been buried with desert sand, but you could still find a piece or two of glass formed when the bomb melted the sand. I took a few pieces home and kept them for years.

Comment: It may be the same kind of a bomb but the conditions are completely different. There is no detectable increase of radiation in Hiroshima and Nagasaki which is what the OP asked about.

Comment: It's a shame you didn't keep the glass. It would be interesting to see what isotopes it contained.

Comment: @JohnRennie Go into any minerals shop in the US and you'll can still pick up "Trinitite" samples fairly cheaply. [This Guy](http://www.tucsonmineral.com/shop_pictures.htm) sells shards for a few dollars. He's much more of a paleontologist though and an afternoon of his time telling you about the mesozoic life of Arizona is well worth the trip to his shop.

Comment: @JohnRennie - I was a kid. I lost it.